# java.lang.ClassCastException: GCWrapper.view._GCWrapperSOAPInterfaceRemote_Stub incompatible with javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, websphere, datasource

I have a Rational Java EE project that I’m building.  I deploy the package to WebSphere 9 on Linux systems.  Everything works correctly if I use `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, `ojdbc8.jar`, and connect with `DriverManager` and a `connection string`.

I have setup a DataSource in Websphere and it connects correctly.

When I have my project try to connect with the data source I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: GCWrapper.view._GCWrapperSOAPInterfaceRemote_Stub incompatible with javax.sql.DataSource
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

code snippet:

```
private static Connection getConnection()
{       
    Connection conn = null;     
    Context initContext = null;
    try {           

        if(_isLocal.Value()){

            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = scanora2017.xxxx.com)(PORT = 2015)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = dkpgcs.xxxx.com)))";
            String user = "wrapper";
            String password = "xxxxx";
            Driver sqlDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(sqlDriver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        }
        else {              
            initContext = new InitialContext();             
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("jdbc/WRAPPERDATASOURCE");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }       
    return conn;
}
```

WebSphere Data Source:
[Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWR9S.png)

JDBC Provider:
[JDBC Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x69SV.png)

Comment: Please provide a code snippet showing how you're using the data source and how the data source and JDBC provider are configured

Comment: The data source is configured in WebSphere. I don't know how to show you.  In WebSphere you can test the connection and it's successful.

Comment: Since the exception is telling you that the object you're looking up thru JNDI isn't a datasource, how the JDBC provider and datasource are configured is important.  If you are able to test the datasource, you're able to see it's configuration

Comment: I added an image of the WebSphere DataSource page.